# Find a duplicate entry and show notification

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet which records the employees Login details with the help of a login userform.
What I want Excel to do is that when the employee click the login button, 
Excel should search the dates coulmn on the sheet and check the cell next to it to verify if the employee has already logged in today. 
If yes, then show a message box and end the program, 
else run my code to store the login details. You can see below how my employees login details are recorded on my login details sheet.

```
NAME OF EMPLOYEE    DATE        TIME

Employee 1          02-02-15    09:05
Employee 2          02-02-15    09:10
```

```html
Sub finddate()
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b1:b500")
    Set c = .Find(Date, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
           MsgBox c.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
    
End With

End Sub
```

I used this above code. It gets me the names of the employees who have logged in today in a message box. Please tell me how can i integrate this process with my userform where it will check if Employee has already logged in.?

Comment: I think you should search the employee column and then compare it's corresponding date if equals today. You can either use `Range Find Method` which returns a `Range Object` or you can use a Loop. Try something out and post your attempted solution here if ever you get stuck.

Comment: @L42 Im sorry im still new to excel...can you help me with the code?

Comment: Try something using this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx then like L42 said paste some code if this does not work. SO won't do the work for you, give it a try before you ask for help

Comment: Update your question instead of commenting, this is hard to read. Also tell us what is working, what is not working and what you are trying to do

Comment: @phil652 Sorry for that.... now see the question.
im only able to get the names of the employees who have already logged i today in a message box!

Comment: If you are able to get the names of the employees who have already logged in today doesn't it answer your question? What else do you need?

Comment: @phil652 what I want is that in the login form when the employee clicks the login button, it should check if he had already logged in and then prevent him from logging in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your form double click the login button you should be able to see where the code is. Then call the function

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
   Call finddate
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just give me the message boxes and not stop me from running further parts of the code?

Comment: Yes but you could add a `if user alreadyLoggedIn = true then Unload Me`

Comment: Should that be added in the Login Button code?
is "if user alreadyLoggedIn = true" a code which can be used?

Comment: Not if you don't create the variables. This was just pseudo code. After you have your msgbox telling you the user already logged in you can add `Unload Me` to close the form so the user can't go any further. If you want the form to stay open you could use `Exit Sub`

Comment: Exit Sub would close stop the program as soon as the message box is found.
In a senario where 3 employees have logged in and the 4th employee is clicking the login button, it would show him also the message box saying that Employee 1 has already logged in and then Stop the form>

Comment: This was not include in your question. When the login button is pressed you will need to get the employee name/number then check only the dates where the employee name/number match. You can do that the same way you did to check if the date match

Comment: it is included in my question.

Comment: At least now you know how to get started if you run into any problems you can ask another question.

Comment: Post what you tried, either do a new question or update this. Also try to be more specific in what you are trying to do this way you will get less vague answers